# Getting an object property via a string name of the property in Python

Tags: python, django

In the following code `data_var` is my object from a Django query, i.e.  `data_var = Datavar.objects.all()`. I have database fields like `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, etc. In the following code I am trying to get the name of the field as a string in `var` and then say `tg.var` but I get an error as object has no attribute 'var':

If I say `tg.var` it should be interpreted as `tg.field1` or `2` or `3`. How to achieve this?

```
for tg in data_var:
     for col in range(content.no_of_cols):
        var = "field" + str(col)
        tg.var
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected output should be? An example would be nice.

Comment: i have hight lighted it.tg.var should be assumed as tg.field1 etc....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get object's attribute with a string name you should use `getattr` built-in function, and that way transforms your code to the next lines:

```
for tg in data_var:
     for col in range(content.no_of_cols):
        var = "field" + str(col)
        value = getattr(tg, var)
```

[gettatr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) is explained in Python doc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying variable variables like in PHP. Python doesn't have it. You need to use a dictionary or getattr.

(Edit-ing since the first answer already covers getattr).

You can also refer to it from the dict:

```
>>> var = 'field1'
>>> tg.__dict__[var]
'this is field1'
>>> var = 'field2'
>>> tg.__dict__[var]
'this is field2'
>>> getattr(tg, var)
'this is field2'
```